# how to show number inside a circle instead of bullets in ion-slide ionic2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm using ionic 2+ and angular 5 , I made a  ion-slides with pager=true, so the bullets appear in the end of every slide, I need to replace the bullets by numbers how to do that? 
it's basic ion-slides:

```
 <ion-slides [pager]="true">
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let itemof items; let i = index">

      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: post you code html and also ts file

Comment: it's basic ion-slide no need for typescript code , even i updated my answer

Comment: So you got solution

Comment: ion-slides just have 3 type of pagination. You can change it through `paginationType` propertive. Sadly, number inside circle is not a built-in type so you have to hand code it